# erlang epmd is not operational

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, epmd

I am trying to connect ejabberd to node on remote server, but can't ping node. Both node running with `-name 'n1@host1.my'` and `-name 'n2@host2.my'` with kernel options `-kernel inet_dist_listen_min 4370 inet_dist_listen_max 4370` , port 4370 is accessible (checked it with telnet on host1.my):

```
telnet host2.my 4370
Trying 34.252.148.114...
Connected to dt.mantu.im.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

in erl:

```
   net_adm:names(). 
    {error,address}
```

that mean epmd is not operational,  but

```
/usr/lib/erlang/erts-9.1.5/bin/epmd -names
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name dev at port 4370
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port `4369`  (epmd daemon port) also should be open